# Does damage to an attribute heal naturally?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-7e

Some attacks or spells may cause damage to an Investigator's attribute score.

For example, in the module *Dead Light*, the titular creature has an attack:

> **Consume (fighting maneuver):** If it succeeds it melds inside its victim. The victim suffers 1D10+5 CON damage per turn until dead, dying in agony as deathly light pulses from within their flesh and boils from their eyes and mouth, and the their flesh begins to burn and turn to ash (Sanity roll for viewing the Dead Light consume a victim is 1/1D6 loss).

If the investigator somehow survives this attack, will they ever recover the lost CON from this horrible assault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The rules are silent on this

But everything suggests that you do not recover damage caused on your attributes. The only damage types that can be recovered according to the rules are *hit points*, with *First Aid/Medicine*, and *sanity*, with *Psychoanalisys*. Other than that, *magic points* are also recovered naturally, unless they are spent in a permanent form (such as casting certain spells).

However, there are creature entries in the book that mention that their damage is permanent, such as Y'golonac's Bite attack:

> Bite: In combat against more than one enemy, Y’golonac uses his mouths to devour and destroy foes. **Damage done by the mouths does not heal naturally and INT and POW loss is permanent, since the suppurating wounds never close**.

Either this was a mistake, or they were merely trying to make the ability sound scarier than it already was. Regardless, the description of this ability is very similar to that of *Dead Light*, and I would rule it similarly, it cannot be healed because that part of your body was destroyed.